# Unable to connect remote Postgresql server from Ubuntu by ODBC

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, odbc

I have two machines:

1. Windows, running PostgreSQL
2. Ubuntu linux

I need to connect from Linux machine to the PostgreSQL on Windows, using C++ code by ODBC library.

I installed ODBC libraries and PostgreSQL ODBC driver on Linux by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev odbc-postgresql
```

I edited /etc/odbc.ini, added the following DSN:

```
[Mydb]
Driver          = PostgreSQL Unicode
Description     = Test DSN
Servername      = 192.168.11.1
Port            = 5432
Database        = Mydb
UserName        = postgres
Password        = ***
```

I'm trying to connect PostgreSQL from Linux by the following C++ code:

```
SQLDriverConnectA(..., "Mydb", SQL_NTS, "postgres", SQL_NTS, "****", SQL_NTS);
```

And this code works fine.

**But I need a solution without adding any DSN ("DSN-less")**. I changed my C++ code this way:

```
SQLCHAR* cs = "DRIVER=PostgreSQL Unicode; Server=192.168.11.1; Port=5432; Database=Mydb; UID=postgres; PWD=****";
SQLDriverConnectA(..., cs, ...);
```

Run on Linux machine, this code gives me an error:

```
connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

The error message looks strange, because I'm trying to connect a remote server, not a local one.

How to fix the DSN-less connection on Linux? I tried "Servername" and "Hostname" instead of "Server" in connection string, but it did not help.

PS. Run on Windows machine, DNS-less code works fine.

PPS. The contents of `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[PostgreSQL ANSI]
Description=PostgreSQL ODBC driver (ANSI version)
Driver=psqlodbca.so
Setup=libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug=0
CommLog=1
UsageCount=1

[PostgreSQL Unicode]
Description=PostgreSQL ODBC driver (Unicode version)
Driver=psqlodbcw.so
Setup=libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug=0
CommLog=1
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: It is not clear to me where the Postgres server is installed(Ubuntu or Windows) and where the client code is being run? Add clarification to question text. Also to question add Postgres version and ODBC driver version and where you got it from?

Comment: According to https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config-opt.html it is spelled "Servername" not "Server"

Comment: I have usually seen it as `Server = ` per [Connect to Postgres](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-postgresql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16). As I remember it `Servername` is used in config files like `odbc.ini`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Postgresql is installed on a remote Windows machine

Comment: @jjanes using `Servername` gives the same error message

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ODBC library and driver was installed using `apt-get odbc odbc-postgresql`. How can I view the version?

Comment: You still have not explained what the layout is? We know the Postgres server is. We don't know where Visual Studio Code is and the settings you used in it to connect? Also not sure what `I have a machine with Ubuntu.' is supposed to mean? And again where is the C++ client, that is failing, running? You need to be explicit in you description as we are not sitting in front of your computer to see ourselves. **Provide all this as update to question**. No need to repeat in comments.

Comment: To get the `odbc-postgresql` package info do `apt info odbc-postgresql`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver rewrote my question from scratch

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Package: odbc-postgresql Version: 1:13.02.0000-2

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Because when I try(on Ubuntu  Ubuntu 20.04)  `sudo apt-get odbc odbc-dev odbc-postgresql` it does not try to  work until I do `sudo apt-get install odbc odbc-dev odbc-postgresql` and that fails with `Unable to locate package odbc Unable to locate package odbc-dev`. I have to use `sudo apt-get install odbcinst  unixodbc-dev odbc-postgresql`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver my misprint :( It was `sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev odbc-postgresql`

Comment: What does `vi /etc/odbcinst.ini` show as installed drivers? Assuming `[PostgreSQL Unicode]` is listed, what does changing to `DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode}...` do?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Added contents of the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` to the post. `DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode}` doesn't help.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I found a solution. The solution is to remove all spaces from the connection string. Without spaces, it works fine. `DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=dell;Port=5432;Database=Mydb;UID=postgres;PWD=***`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove all spaces from the connection string:

```
DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=dell;Port=5432;Database=Mydb;UID=postgres;PWD=***
```

Without spaces, it works fine.